# Sonata Admin Bundle on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I want to use Bootstrap in configureFormField. But it does not work.

My code :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) <br>
    { <br>
         $formMapper <br>
         ->with('Content', ['class' => 'col-md-6']) <br>
            ->add('texte', 'textarea') <br>
        ->end() <br>
        ;
    }
```

thanks for your help :)

Comment: what do you exactly mean "doesn't work"? the size of your block doesn't change? the block doesn't have `col-md-6` class? the page isn't being rendered? can you see any exceptions or errors?

Comment: I want my textarea to measure "col-md-6". I have not exception or errors and my page is being rendered.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes in your php code. I also tried it, and it works fine. Does your textarea have "col-md-6" class? If it does, but the size doesn't change, check if bootstrap css, js, etc are included properly.